# Selenium web driver is not going to next automatically opened tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium

on clicking a login button on webpage a new tab is opened asking fro login but selenium web driver is not able to recognise the elements and the execution is aborted in chrome

Answer (score 0):

please check this out:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```